# How to instal python basemap on MacOS?

Tags: python

For the past 5 hours, I have been trying to install basemap module on my laptop. I have tried various methods and apparently they do not work. Firstly I have tried the one that was posted on stackoverflow 5 years ago using brew, but when you download zip file, it does not contain installer(that what terminal says). I was trying to install it directly from the terminal, also did not work. Official documentation on the installation of the package (https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html) is complicated and I could not understand the steps. Can someone please tell me how to install it on MacOS?

P.S. I am working in the jupyter and currently trying to install the package using Anaconda

Comment: Beyond `export GEOS_DIR=/usr/local`, what is unclear from the linked page?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am confused by that exact part. I installed Geos using pip3, but i do not understand where do I find those repositories they ask for usr/local/lib and geos_c.h for example this. And what do i do exactly in the terminal? Thank you!

Comment: The site asks you to download and build geos from source, not install via pip https://libgeos.org/usage/download/

Comment: @OneCricketeer okay so I built it from the source and I used ./configure --prefix=$GEOS_DIR
make; make install, following the tutorial, but when i get back to basemap folder, i still cant install setuo.py, as it can not find GEOS_DIR. What is actually GEOS_DIR?

Comment: What do you mean you cannot find it? It's a variable that you defined. The make command should put files under that prefix path. In other words, `cd $GEOS_DIR`